# Spring Boot @PreAuthorize annotation doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I have a big problem using `@PreAuthorize`. Spring Boot doesn't seem to pick up on the fact that the currently logged in user does have the necessary role to perform the action, as the user gets its role in the `getAuthorities()` method in my user implementation below:

The exception I get

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attempt
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:257)
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.issue.tracker.ticket.TicketController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createTicket(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
```

etc... (I will include further logs upon request, but the rest seem to be just filler)

Relevant configuration (if I miss something just let me know):

My configuration class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .headers(header -> header.frameOptions().sameOrigin())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    // ...stuff for JWT tokens to work, Bcrypt, other stuff, etc. not included

}
```

My user entity implementation

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Slf4j
class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password_")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> userRoles = roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        log.info(userRoles.toString());

        // And yes, upon logging in, I do get the ROLE_ADMIN role 
        // in the logs, so it's not like a problem with the user 
        // itself not having the role

        return userRoles;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My controller

```java
@RequestMapping("/ticket")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
class TicketController {

    private final TicketServiceImpl ticketService;

    private final CustomModelMapper modelMapper;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public TicketDto createTicket(@RequestBody @Valid TicketDto ticketDto) {
        Ticket ticketRequest = modelMapper.map(ticketDto, Ticket.class);

        Ticket ticket = ticketService.createTicket(ticketRequest);

        return modelMapper.map(ticket, TicketDto.class);
    }
}
```

- Spring version: 6.0.4
- Java version: 19.0.1

Some of the things I've tried so far:

1. Replacing my userDetailsService implementation to check if the problem is with my User implementation after all:

   ```java
   @Bean
   public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
       UserDetails theManager = User.withUsername("admin1")
               .passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()::encode)
               .password("admin1").roles("ADMIN").build();

       InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();

       userDetailsManager.createUser(theManager);

       return userDetailsManager;
   }
   ```

```
2. Changing my **@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")** to:

    - `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`
    - `hasRole('ADMIN')`
    - I also tried changing `@PreAuthorize` to `@RolesAllowed` (with the necessary `jsr250Enabled=true` on the `@EnableMethodSecurity` annotation in the config class of course)
    - Removing the `@Valid` annotation from the controller method parameter

None of these things have worked and I'm all out of ideas and have no clue how to proceed from here.
```

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`  to your `application.properties`  and check the `Authentication` object and its authorities. I think that if you are providing a JWT, the authorities are prefixed with `SCOPE_`

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Not the hero I deserved, but the hero I needed. You have no idea how much you've just helped me. I've been banging my head against a wall for 2 days over this. I don't know why it never occurred to me to just use TRACE level debugging. It is indeed prefixed with SCOPE_ , so the app thinks the role should be SCOPE_ROLE_ADMIN... Thank you very much again.

Comment: @dur It kind of does, but I already solved it going off of MarcusHertdaCoregio's answer, but extra info is always appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to @MarcusHertdaCoregio

Upon using TRACE level debugging, I found out that Marcus was right, if you are providing JWT, all your roles will be prefixed with **SCOPE_** by default. So if you want your @PreAuthorize to work, just ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER is not going to work by itself, you need to use SCOPE_ROLE_ADMIN or SCOPE_ROLE_USER and so on.

Comment: If you want, you can remove the prefix as well, take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction